# Явный и не явный возврат функции, что это значит и в чем разница?

Tags: javascript

Может кто-то по-простому объяснить, какая разница между явным и не явным возвратом функции и что это значит?

Comment: Без return в стрелочной функции - неявный возврат. Что тут может озадачить?

Answer (score 5):

Любая функция в JavaScript что-то возвращает. Если вы руками в функции написали ключевое слово `return` - то это явный возврат. Будет явно возвращено указанное значение: `return 'a'` вернет строку `'a'`, просто `return;` вернет `undefined`.

Если же ключевое слово `return` отсутствует, то такой возврат называется неявным. Что именно будет возвращено, зависит от сигнатуры функции. В большинстве случаев это будет `undefined`, но в случае с, например, асинхронными функциями, будет неявно возвращен `Promise`, который разрешается в `undefined`.

Можно сделать функцию, которая имеет как явное, так и неявное возвращаемое значение:

```
function foo () {
  if (condition) return "bar";
}
```

Здесь мы явно возвращаем `"bar"` если выполняется условие. В противном случае будет неявно возвращен `undefined`.

Единственные 2 случая, когда функция не возвращает никакого значения, это в случаях:

1. Использования оператора `yield` (но при этом рано или поздно, если не выполняется второй пункт, все равно будет что-то возвращено. Просто не сразу)
2. Если функция выбрасывает исключение

Просто вопрос терминологии, не забивайте себе этим голову особо.

Comment: Думаю это более верный ответ с технической точки зрения. Функция у которой нет return всё же **неявно** возвращает undefined.

Answer (score 4):

**Неявный и явный возврат**

У нас есть несколько способов написания наших стрелочных функций. Это потому, что стрелочные функции могут иметь ключевое слово «подразумеваемый возврат» или «явный возврат».

В обычных функциях, если вы хотите что-то вернуть, вам нужно использовать ключевое слово return. В стрелочных функциях тоже есть return. Когда вы используете return, это называется явным возвратом . Тем не менее, стрелка позволяет делать так называемый подразумеваемый возврат, когда return ключевое слово можно пропустить. Давайте посмотрим на несколько примеров:

**Пример 1**: нормальное функциональное выражение

```
const sayHi = function(name) {
  return name;
}
```

**Пример 2**: стрелочная функция с явным возвратом

```
    // Multi-line
    const sayHi = (name) => {
      return name;
    }

 
// Single-line
const sayHi = (name) => { return name }
```

**Пример 3**: стрелочная функция с неявным возвратом

```
// Single-line
const sayHi = (name) => name
 
// Multi-line
const sayHi = (name) => (
  name = 'Hi, ' + name,
  name
)
```

Когда вы используете фигурные скобки `{}`, вам нужно явно указать возврат. Однако, когда вы не используете фигурные скобки, return подразумевается, и вам этого делать не нужно.

Более подробно можно почитать тут
https://ivan-shamaev.ru/javascript-notes-for-web-development/#i-7

> что это значит

Ответ мне видится таким - это просто некое синтаксическое сокращение

> в чем разница?

Визуальная - в наличии или отсутствии `return`.

В использовании никакой разницы нет. Функция как функция.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то еще одна важная разница между явным и неявным возвратом - это возможность добавить промежуточные операции **до** возврата значения. С явным возвратом (фигурные скобки + return) это возможно, а с неявным - нет. Поправьте, если не прав

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, это не совсем так. Посмотри пример с круглыми скобками. При неявном возврате в них можно писать любые выражения. Это конечно не все возможности при фигурных скобках... Но таки возможность написать еще что-то "до" возврата - есть. :)

Comment: Подскажите, что там еще можно написать?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, любые выражения. Да хоть список вызываемых функций...

Comment: А без круглых скобок это невозможно сделать? Я просто пытаюсь понять, какие доп преимущества дают круглые скобки в примере 3

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, я изменил в примере функцию `sayHi`. Добавил одно выражение для демонстрации. Но без круглых скобок такое сделать не получится. Как вариант, неявный вызов можно делать с квадратными скобками `[]`. Так будет возвращаться массив. А вот как он будет создаваться - уже фантазия автора. :) Ведь элементы массива могут формироваться довольно сложно...

Comment: Понял, спасибо за дополнение к ответу. Получается, просто даем движку javascript понять приоритеты операций и пользуемся особенностью оператора `,`.